# Сбор блатных и нищих

Tags: этимология, фразеология, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Не объяснит ли кто-нибудь значение этого не слишком расхожего фразеологизма?
Узнать его происхождение тоже было бы интересно.

Comment: Помню это выражение ещё с 1960-х годов. Видимо, оно бытовало и в сороковые - и ранее...(Есть основания у меня так полагать).

Answer (score 1):

Более полный вариант: Сбор блатных и шайка нищих
Интересное толкование:Жарг. шк. Шутл.-ирон. Родительское собрание. (Запись 2003 г.).

Comment: Это только одно из значений. Очевидно, что не единственное.

Comment: Может  и  не  единственное,  зато  из  жизни.  Остальные  лишь  толкования.

Comment: Достаточно  меткое  выражение.

Answer (score 1):

В [этимологическом словаре](https://krylov.academic.ru/3302) Г. А. Крылова говорится:

**сброд**
Это слово, называющее группу разложившихся людей, восходит к глаголу *сбрестись*. Буквально ― "те, кто сбились (сбрелись) в одну группу, стаю".

Я думаю, что изначально фраза звучала так: **сброд** (= орава, сборище) **блатных и шайка нищих.**

В подтверждение приведу цитату.

*Он рассматривал возбужденно орущих пацанов и печально улыбался. Почти все выросли из убоговатой призывной одежды и больше всего походили на хулиганистых детдомовцев-переростков, вывезенных на долгожданную экскурсию.

И провожали их, как детдомовцев. Горячий ветер пустыни мел песок по бетонке аэродрома, трепал отросшие волосы на выжигаемых полуденным солнцем неприкрытых головах. Раскатов, недовольно морщась, прошелся вдоль строя разномастно одетых парней – брюнетов, шатенов, блондинов, рыжих...

**– Сброд блатных и шайка нищих!** – не особо стараясь приглушить голос, бросил он через плечо шагающему следом Чучканову. – Почему я должен видеть своих солдат в таком виде?*
[Д. Корецкий. Татуированная кожа. 2000](https://unotices.com/book.php?id=10074&page=51)

[**Пояснение**
[Д. А. Корецкий](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB_%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) — советский и российский учёный-криминолог, писатель и сценарист. Доктор юридических наук, профессор, заслуженный юрист Российской Федерации, полковник милиции в отставке, почётный сотрудник МВД.]

И ещё одну.

*— Тетя Гера, а партизаны имели присягу?

— А ты думал, что партизаны — это **сброд блатных и шайка нищих**? Ошибаешься, Семенцов! У нас клятва была такая, что похлеще воинской.*
[А. Литвинов. Германский вермахт в русских кандалах](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=52741&p=59)

**Сброд блатных и шайка нищих** — это большое количество (скопище) разношерстных, разномастных, неоднородых, пестрых, разносословных людей.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, тут слово "блатной" употреблено не в значении "по блату", а в смысле "уголовник". То есть, "сбор блатных и нищих" - собрание попрошаек и преступников.
Поправьте, если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Можно  предположить,  что  это  нечто  несуразное,  если  толковать  блатного  как  человека  со  связями.  Тогда  "сбор  блатных  и  нищих" - это  чёрт  знает  что !

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд это чисто милицейское выражение. - Кто там у тебя сегодня в клетке?- спрашивает начальник РОВД дежурного. - Да, как обычно, - **сбор блатных и нищих**!" Почему я считаю именно так, - достаточно подробно изложено в ответе на вопрос - "и снова о блатных".